# Pyspark - avoiding array error java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Requested array size exceeds VM limit

Tags: python, arrays, pyspark

I've a legacy application that'll be deprecated in few months. It is reading contents of a file line-by-line in an array and for some unexpected larger files, the application throws `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Requested array size exceeds VM limit` exception.

`Update: This code runs as a PySpark job in AWS Glue. Hence, a java exception is being reported.`

Without putting a lot of effort, I wish to solve this problem for the time being.

I'm wondering if checking for the size (or length) of array to see if it has exceeded max limit is a good idea to avoid occurrence of `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Requested array size exceeds VM limit` error?

```
# Pyspark code below
log_lines = []
for line in log_file:
  log_lines.append(line)
  if(len(log_lines)>100000) # limit the size of array to be 100000
     process_part(log_lines) # process the array i.e. write it somewhere and continue
     log_lines = []

if len(log_lines)>0:
   process_part(log_lines)
```

Comment: How is it exactly that you're getting a _Java_ error when running _python_ code? Are you executing with Jython or something?

Comment: The code is wrapped in a pyspark script ran from a AWS glue ETL job... I've updated my question to reflect this..

Comment: this doesn't look like PySpark code to me, or the PySpark code does not show up in the question, do you mind updating it?